# Put Greendroid actionbar on the bottom

Tags: android, android-actionbar, greendroid

is there a chance to locate the greendroid actionbar (or another action bar) on the bottom of the layout? I tried to change the gravity of the ActionBar to Bottom, but it had no effect.

I'm new with this technology so if someone could help me I will be very greatful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Without touching the source, I don't think you can.

But *GreenDroid* is made to help us **follow the Android UI Design Patterns**, so why would you use GreenDroid to **not** follow them?

But if you really want to, take a look at the other ActionBar library projects, as I hope one will allow you to do what you want.

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock